# What is the best approach to filter data in SQL (Dynamic Query)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to return a result set from a table filtered according to parameters provided.

**UPDATE**

```
alter procedure  Proc_CheckExchange     
@Flag varchar(3),      
@symbol varchar(13)=null,        
@exchange char(3)=null,        
@limit money=null,        
@chargerate numeric(18,4)=null,        
@ChgType char(2)=null,        
@IsActive int=null,        
@Mkrid varchar(11)=null,        
@statecode varchar(4) =null    


as         
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)  

set @sql = N'select * from Tbl_StampDutyException1 where 1 = 1'  
if(@Flag='CHK')      
begin   


if len(isnull(@exchange, '')) > 0  
  set  @sql = @sql + N'and exchange=@exchange'+ cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))  

if len(isnull(@symbol, '')) > 0  
 set   @sql = @sql + N'and symbol=@symbol'+ cast(@symbol as nvarchar(100))  

if len(isnull(@limit, '')) > 0  
 set   @sql = @sql + N'and limit=@limit'+ cast(@limit as nvarchar(100))  

if len(isnull(@chargerate, '')) > 0  
  set  @sql = @sql + N'and chargerate=@chargerate'+ cast(@chargerate as nvarchar(100))  

if len(isnull(@ChgType, '')) > 0  
 set   @sql = @sql + N'and ChgType=@ChgType'+ cast(@ChgType as nvarchar(100))  

if len(isnull(@IsActive, '')) > 0  
  set  @sql = @sql + N'and IsActive=@IsActive'+ cast(@IsActive as nvarchar(100))  

    if len(isnull(@statecode, '')) > 0  
 set   @sql = @sql + N'and statecode=@statecode'+ cast(@statecode as nvarchar(100))  



exec (@sql)  
end  

if (@Flag='ALL')      
begin    
 select * from Tbl_StampDutyException1   
end
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
    alter procedure  Proc_CheckExchange     
@Flag varchar(3),      
@symbol varchar(13)=null,        
@exchange char(3)=null,        
@limit money=null,        
@chargerate numeric(18,4)=null,        
@ChgType char(2)=null,        
@IsActive int=null,        
@Mkrid varchar(11)=null,        
@statecode int =null    


as         
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)  

set @sql = N'select * from Tbl_StampDutyException1 where 1 = 1'  
if(@Flag='CHK')      
begin   

  if len(isnull(@exchange, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and exchange = @exchange'

   if len(isnull(@limit, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and limit = @limit'

    if len(isnull(@chargerate, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and chargerate = @chargerate'

    if len(isnull(@ChgType, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and ChgType = @ChgType'

    if len(isnull(@IsActive, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and IsActive = @IsActive'

    if len(isnull(@statecode, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and statecode = @statecode'

    if len(isnull(@symbol, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and symbol = @symbol'

 declare @params as nvarchar(max) = N'@Flag varchar(3), 
@symbol varchar(13),        
@exchange char(3),        
@limit money,        
@chargerate numeric(18,4),        
@ChgType char(2),        
@IsActive int,        
@Mkrid varchar(11),        
@statecode varchar(4)'
print @sql
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params, @Flag, @symbol, @exchange, @limit, @chargerate, @ChgType,    @IsActive, @Mkrid, @statecode

    end
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure in which there will be as many conditions in `WHERE` clause as passed to the stored procedure. I hope I am clear about what I am trying to achieve. I am getting error `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: Try not to write stored procs like that. You may have problems with cached execution plans if you use so many `if`s. You will have one execution plan but each time you call your stored proc it may require a new one. I guess you could rewrite it using dynamic SQL (which will help to solve your problem too).

Comment: Why do you have `where` instead of `and`?

Comment: @Gabe my bad.. sorry. I have corrected that but still no luck.

Comment: You also have `exchange=@exchange'+ cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))` which will produce something like `exchange=@exchangeABC`. Either use the `@exchange` with `sp_executesql` or use `cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))` with proper quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to rewrite your stored proc using dynamic SQL and include parts of `where` clause only if parameters are defined, e.g. replace the body with

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'select * from Tbl_StampDutyException1 where 1 = 1'

if len(isnull(@exchange, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and exchange = ' + cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))

-- add all parameters; you need to cast them to nvarchar if they have other type

exec (@sql)
```

---

As an improvement, you can use `sp_executesql` to execute dynamic SQL. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) on how to use it. In this case, the code will be:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'select * from Tbl_StampDutyException1 where 1 = 1'

if len(isnull(@exchange, '')) > 0
    set @sql = @sql + N' and exchange = @exchange'

-- add all parameters;

declare @params as nvarchar(max) = N'@Flag varchar(3), 
@symbol varchar(13),        
@exchange char(3),        
@limit money,        
@chargerate numeric(18,4),        
@ChgType char(2),        
@IsActive int,        
@Mkrid varchar(11),        
@statecode varchar(4)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params, @Flag, @symbol, @exchange, @limit, @chargerate, @ChgType,    @IsActive, @Mkrid, @statecode
```

---

By the way, don't use `select *` in stored procedures, it's not a good practice. List all the columns you want to return. Otherwise, if the table definition changes, you will get different result to what it was previously.

Comment: Sorry, forgot one `set`. Check now.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: You should probably look at `sp_executesql`. You can specify parameter types then.

Comment: Um, I guess I am missing out something .. I think this should work `sp_executesql Proc_CheckExchange   'chk','','','','','','','','' `  right?

Comment: I am still getting Error `converting data type varchar to numeric.` I have updated my code.

Comment: That may be data related. Can you replace `exec (@sql)` with `print (@sql)` - this will print out the dynamic sql. You'll be able to see the problems then.

Comment: I am still getting same error .. I have replaced `exec` with `print`

Comment: Ok, I've noticed now. Instead of `exchange=@exchange'+ cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))` you should have `exchange='+ cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))`. Also, depending on the data type, you may have to ds `exchange='''+ cast(@exchange as nvarchar(100))+ ''''`

Comment: I added a code for sp_executesql, that may be easier for you.

Comment: I think problem is at `chargerate` when I pass a numeric value I do not get any errors but if i try and pass `'' or null` I get error

Comment: @syzymon I tried your new code, although I am no longer getting any error but It always returns all rows.. placed `print @sql` and I got `select * from Tbl_StampDutyException1 where 1 = 1` although i passed 

` Proc_CheckExchange 'chk','ASE-PLTNUM',null,null,null,null,null,'',8 `

Comment: You put `@exchange` into every if condition. Please use proper variables.

Comment: For those that are not `char`, you don't need `len`, just `if @chargerate is not null` is enough.

Comment: Thank you, so much. It works. Btw can you please explain the 2nd half of your answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42302/discussion-between-szymon-and-arbaaz)

Answer (score 2):

I think that a good solution would be this one

```sql
SELECT * from dbo.Clients
WHERE 
    (@param1 IS NULL OR field1 = @param1)
AND (@param2 IS NULL OR field2 = @param2)
```

With this approach the statement will not be re-processed (execution plan) by the server every time you execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

What I guess you need is a CONDITIONAL WHERE CLAUSE approach, have provided the sample script below, you need to convert all the IF conditions to a CASE and you then you can combine all the conditions into a single SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_StampDutyException1   
WHERE 
exchange = CASE WHEN @exchange='' or @exchange is  null THEN exchange ELSE @exchange END
AND symbol = Case when @symbol='' or @symbol is  null  THEN symbol ELSE symbol   
AND *so on.....*
```

Comment: While this will work in all cases, it will quite possibly cause a less optimal query plan because SQL Server doesn't know ahead of time that it doesn't need to check all those columns that the user isn't querying against.

Comment: @Gabe I agree, Szymon's approach is more optimized one.