# Invalid variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This stored procedure works until I add in a variable. The `@sWHERE` variable will be populated from a a fixed input.

I'm not sure what I need to amend ...I've tried adding & and +

> **Error:** 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spUniqueUPRN, Line 12 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'Group'.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
USE [DB]
GO 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUniqueUPRN]    
@sWHERE varchar(Max) 
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;   
SELECT  DISTINCT UPRN INTO TBLTEMP FROM TblA
WHERE  @sWHERE
Group BY UPRN
UNION ALL
SELECT  UPRN FROM TblP
Group BY UPRN 
END
```

**VERSION 2 based on help so far (no where near final just a step)**

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUniqueUPRN]    
@sWHERE varchar(Max) 
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
---------- 
DROP TABLE TBLTEMP

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'UPRN INTO TBLTEMP FROM TblA ' + QUOTENAME(@sWHERE) + '
Group BY UPRN
UNION ALL
SELECT  UPRN FROM TblP
Group BY UPRN 
';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
---------- 
END
```

**Verion 3**

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUniqueUPRN]    
@sDateFrom Date,
@sDateTo Date,
@sUPRN varchar(Max),
@sRiskRating varchar(10),
@sSurveyCompany varchar(Max),
@sPostcode varchar(10),
@sStreet varchar(Max),
@sRegion Int

AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
---------- 
DROP TABLE TBLTEMP

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT UPRN INTO TBLTEMP FROM TblA WHERE 1 = 1 ' 
IF QUOTENAME(@sDateFrom) IS NOT NULL AND QUOTENAME(@sDateTo) IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' or SurveyDate BETWEEN ' +  QUOTENAME(@sDateFrom) + ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@sDateTo) + ''''

IF QUOTENAME(@sRiskRating) IS NOT NULL 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' or OverAllRiskCategory = ' + QUOTENAME(@sRiskRating)    +''''

IF QUOTENAME(@sUPRN) IS NOT NULL 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' or UPRN LIKE ' + QUOTENAME(@sUPRN) + ''''

IF QUOTENAME(@sSurveyCompany) IS NOT NULL 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' or SurveyCompany LIKE ''%' +  QUOTENAME(@sSurveyCompany)  + '%'''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' GROUP BY UPRN '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' UNION ALL '


SELECT  UPRN FROM TblProperty
 IF QUOTENAME(@sPostcode) IS NOT NULL 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' or Postcode  LIKE ''%' +   QUOTENAME(@sPostcode)  + '%'''

IF QUOTENAME(@sStreet) IS NOT NULL 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' or Street  LIKE ''%' +  QUOTENAME(@sStreet)  + '%'''

IF QUOTENAME(@sRegion) IS NOT NULL 
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'or Region  LIKE ''%' +  QUOTENAME(@sRegion)  + '%'''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'GROUP BY UPRN'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
---------- 
END
```

Comment: What is the value of `@sWHERE`?  You can't just say `WHERE @sWHERE`.  That doesn't work.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for custom `WHERE` passed as string. Anyway  user may pass `EXEC dbo.spUniqueUPRN '1=1; DROP TABLE ....; --` So prepare for **[SQL injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: @ sWHERE will come from an import depending on user input @roryap

Comment: @indofraiser -- please don't do that.  That is a **terrible** idea.  You should read up on SQL injection before you go any further.

Comment: I'll rephrase, the user can not add any values it's looking to see if there are specific values selected or not. No textual user input. However I take the point on board. I will be adding some additions for security to. I forget the name for now mind that goes around it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best approach to filter data in SQL (Dynamic Query)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297752/what-is-the-best-approach-to-filter-data-in-sql-dynamic-query)

Comment: No matter what the user inputs or not you CAN'T (language definition) use a variable as part of a statement like that. Also I'm pretty sure that a group by before a union is also wrong. You have to create a dynamic query as suggested by @lad2025 see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297752/what-is-the-best-approach-to-filter-data-in-sql-dynamic-query

Comment: I don't understand the down voting. I've had a crack at a solution and come for help. Shame really. Thanks for the above help though :-)

Comment: Besides what's been said before, you are using a `group by` without aggregating, and a combination of `group by` and `distinct`. These two can have the same result, but I always find it best to use `group by` for aggregation, and `distinct` to select unique rows. A combination of the two is always superfluous.

Comment: Thanks all, right I'll do some research based on the above and come back with updates including QUOTENAME etc...

Comment: For purposes of Stack Overflow, a question doesn't have to be exactly the same to be a duplicate.   If the answer to the other question also answers your question, then it can and should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: I did not downvoted you. I'm actually trying to help you. It seems that you didn't understand your problem yet. An sql statement must be immutable. you cant add dynamic parts of it with variables it is not allowed by the language. This `SELECT a.somecol FROM @myTableVariables;` this is wrong you have to define some text variable and concatenate your query as a text than dynamic execute it like on the link that was given to you.

Comment: **[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)** => In your case it will be rather curse

Comment: Something like `@myDynSql = "select a.somecol FROM " + @myTableVariables;` then use the commands to execute this string as a query.

Comment: @JorgeCampos quite right, I've amended my test data to Dynamic so far I am at V2 (in edited post)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Great suggestion for sql injection. Note that entire part is passed as string not parametrized value.

Comment: @lad2025 besides that problem which is another one, it is in the purpose of the OPs understand. But you are right though.

Comment: @lad2025 yes the joys and pain of life hey. I'll have a good read.

Comment: @indofraiser Please read **[SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition)** Anyway it is up to you which path you will go. Good luck.

Comment: @indofraiser Are you still having the same error after the change? If yes you should consider to take out the group by before the union `...Group BY UPRN UNION ALL SELECT  UPRN...` must be `...UNION ALL SELECT  UPRN...`

Comment: @JorgeCampos no error now. I might close this and once I've read http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html reference this and start with cleaner (bat). I know it was not right but was not sure where to turn next.

Comment: @lad2025 if you put the answer as 'read http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html; then I'll accept that as I will then close this off, read it all (good so far) and come back with an updated code if required (or peer review to check no holes!!) Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to pass `@sWHERE` as string to stored procedure you need to use dynamic SQL.

Before you use dynamic SQL I strongly recommend to read **[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)**.

Your case is [SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition):

> If you are considering to write the procedure
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE search_sp @condition varchar(8000) AS 
> SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition
> ```
>
> **Just forget it. If you are doing this, you have not completed the transition to use stored procedure and you are still assembling your
>   SQL code in the client.** But this example lapses into Dynamic Search Conditions/Dynamic Crosstab.

The point is that you could use (as proposed in comments)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT *
  FROM table_name
  WHERE ' + @sWHERE;

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql
       @sql;
```

But this is straight way to [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) attacks. User may call:

```
EXEC dbo.spUniqueUPRN '1=1; DROP TABLE ....; --'
```

To sum up, it is up to you if you will use `WHERE @condition`. It is possible but I would not go this path.

Comment: Thanks to all. Hopefully version 3 is much closer but I'll start a new thread or it starts to make no sense!