# How to create a tag based on non mutually exclusive fields

Tags: sql

I have three different boolean columns (A, B, C) in the source data.
Something like...

| Record | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | T | F | F |
| Second | F | T | T |
| Third | F | F | F |
| Fourth | T | F | T |
| Fifth | T | T | T |

I want to use this table as the basis for a dashboard with a filter. This filter should be able to return all records which are True on that particular column.

For example, if one was to select 'A' in the filter, it should return the First, Fourth, and Fifth record. If 'B' was to be selected expected return is Second, and Fifth row. For 'C', the expected outcome is Second, Fourth, and Fifth.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and tag the database ?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. And `case` is an _expression_, not statement.

Comment: BTW, the boolean data type has the values TRUE and FALSE. Which data type are you using for your Y/N columns?

Comment: So what is the expected result for the above and why? Is column C relevant? Are these char(1) columns? What is the RDBMS?

Comment: @jarlh I've made the updates to specify the expected results and also corrected the terms.

Comment: Do you simply want `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE A = 'T'` etc?

Comment: I need an approach that creates a filter that would give {'A', 'B', 'C'} as selection choices - where 
'A' will return SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE A = 'T';
'B' will return SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE B = 'T'
'C' will return SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE C = 'T'

Comment: is this help, sql if else https://simplesqltutorials.com/if-elseif-else/   Usually sql is use with program e.g. java, and you could use program if else to determine which sql to send.

Answer (score 0):

This a way to do it :

```
SELECT t.Record
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (select 'T' as [COL]) s on s.[COL] = t.[COL]
```

If column A passed as parameter then :

```
select t.Record
from mytable t
inner join (select 'T' as A) s on s.A = t.A
```

Result :

| Record |
| --- |
| First |
| Fourth |
| Fifth |

Demo tested on mysql : https://dbfiddle.uk/u0hP4vZT

Answer (score 0):

I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297752/what-is-the-best-approach-to-filter-data-in-sql-dynamic-query) relevant here

```
select *
from your_table
where
    ( @param_a is null or your_table.a = @param_a )
    and( @param_b is null or your_table.b = @param_b )
    and ( @param_c is null or your_table.c = @param_c )
```